# Ellipse Animation with QPropertyAnimation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to animate the appearance of an ellipse(so that it turns from a small point into a large ellipse). I read the documentation and looked at various examples, but nothing works. Now there is the following code:

```py
class ellAnimation(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ellAnimation, self).__init__()
        self.mRect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.mItem = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem()
        self.mItem.setRect(self.mLine)
        self.mItem.setPen(
            QPen(QColor("black"), 2))

        self.mAnimation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            self,
            b"rect2",
            parent=self,
            startValue=QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1),
            endValue=QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 500, 500),
            duration=1000,
        )
        self.mAnimation.start()

    def rect1(self):
        return self.mRect.getRect()

    def setRect1(self, rect1):
        self.mRect.setRect(rect1)
        self.mItem.setRect(self.mRect)

    def rect2(self):
        return self.mRect.getRect()

    def setRect2(self, rect2):
        self.mRect.setRect(rect2)
        self.mItem.setRect(self.mRect)

    rect1 = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtCore.QRectF, fget=rect1, fset=setRect1)
    rect2 = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtCore.QRectF, fget=rect2, fset=setRect2)
```

In the main code this way I add to the scene:

`animation = ellAnimation()
self.scene.addItem(animation.mItem)`

This was an attempt to redo the code for line animation. Help me redo it for ellipse animation.

Comment: whats is `mLine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code provided by the OP it is difficult to know where the error is (there are many elements that are not declared, in addition to the fact that the object is not shown), so the cause of the errors could be many, so I will avoid that and I will only show a functional code, instead of the item being inside the QObject and its information being updated I will make the QObject expose the property and update the item through a signal:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ManagerRectAnimation(QtCore.QObject):
    rectChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QRectF)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ManagerRectAnimation, self).__init__(parent)
        self._rect = QtCore.QRectF()

        self._animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            self, targetObject=self, propertyName=b"rect", duration=1000
        )

    @property
    def animation(self):
        return self._animation

    def rect(self):
        return self._rect

    def setRect(self, r):
        self._rect = r
        self.rectChanged.emit(r)

    rect = QtCore.pyqtProperty(
        QtCore.QRectF, fget=rect, fset=setRect, notify=rectChanged
    )


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)

    item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem()
    scene.addItem(item)

    manager_animation = ManagerRectAnimation(view)
    manager_animation.rectChanged.connect(item.setRect)
    manager_animation.animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
    manager_animation.animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 500, 500))
    manager_animation.animation.start()

    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```